# PyDev for Eclipse

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pydev

does it worth to use it? what are the features for better use, and why should i get it?
i have heard that it is a good tool for developing AI algorithms, and i want to know if there is anything special that i can use from it.

for example:

```
var = random.shuffle()
```

this function is used widely at AI, is something better at PyDev?

i'm doing the simulated annealing and the ants algorithms, this function:

```
def Tour(tamaño):
    tour1 = []
    for i in range(tamaño):
        while(not False):
            valor = random.randrange(tamaño)
            if valor not in tour1:
                tour1.append(valor)
                break
    return tour1
```

is to create a random tour, but i heard that using PyDev tool is easier to do it, how?

Comment: 1) there is no `ramdom` module (you're looking for `random`. 2) Pydev is an eclipse plugin that allows eclipse to be an IDE with which you can develop python code. What code you want to develop using that IDE is entirely up to you and pydev does not restrict the kinds of algorithms you can develop. 3) your posted function will not work as posted (syntax error - please fix indentation) 4) it is not simulated annealing; you have no heat/decay terms 5) you can write the code just as well on Vim. pydev doesn't help with specific algorithms - just the language

Comment: 1) it works 2) this is not all the SA algorithm, is just a function to create a random tour (that i use to SA) 3) i edit the ramdom, thanks. 4) thank you for the comments :)

Comment: 6) [`random.shuffle()` takes a list and shuffles it in-place (returns nothing)](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/random.html#random.shuffle). Your `var = random.shuffle()` will raise a `TypeError`, and even if used correctly, `var` will be `None`. 7) You didn't fix the indentation error I raised in (3); I just fixed it for you (you're welcome) 8) your function will still not work as `ñ` is not an ascii character (the interpreter is going to complain)

Comment: again thanks, but i'm telling you, it works ;)